# Can I run multiple instances of elasticsearch on same machine for log aggregation?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logging

I'm little confused here. Please help me out. 
I have a spring-boot application which feeds the data into elasticsearch. This spring-boot runs on AWS instance. Right now, I do not have proper log aggregation and I want to use ELK stack for it. 
Please help me out with these concerns...

1. Can I make a new log cluster on the same elasticsearch instance and feed the log data into it? Is it a good idea?
2. Should I use a different elasticsearch instance on the same machine with different port and direct all the log traffic to this instance?
3. Should I host my elasticsearch onto a new aws server and direct all the traffic? Will latency cause problems on later stages when the log data feed is huge?

Comment: How did you end up going about it?

Answer (score 0):

The set of questions you've asked will have broad and varied answers depending on factors such as volume, velocity and capacity.
Think of an ES cluster as a database. If you have multiple log files/sources, you can insert them into different indexes on the same cluster.

Comment: here is the thing, I use elasticsearch to store the application data and do some data processing with its own index. Can I use the same cluster for logs as well with a different index?

Comment: Elasticsearch is like a database engine, you can have multiple databases(indices) and each database(index) can have multiple tables(Types) {maybe not anymore?}. Having said that your choice depends on your analysis/search needs